# Updating NgIf value using an @input property in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

Good evening. This is my first question here, I expect don't messed up. I'm trying to hide/show an HTML fragment in a component using a value that I got from another component through an @input property, my actual code looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'test-animation',
    template: `
        <h1>The value is {{show}} </h1> (1)
        <span *ngIf="show"> show me! </span>` (2)
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {    
    @Input() show: boolean = false;    
    constructor() { }    
    ngOnInit() {    
    }    
}
```

I'm using it like this in another component:

```
<test-animation show="{{showAnimation}}"></test-animation>
```

"showAnimation" is a variable that I dynamically change in the second component using a (click) event. Now the issue: even thought the interpolation (1) works as expected and reflect the change of the value, the ngIf (2) seems not be affected. I have tried using a get property, different templates syntaxes but the change it is not reflected in the ngIf. I checked the event ngonchanges and the value is changing.

After some hours of testing and research in the documentation, Google, and here, I understood that my code is failing to report the change on the property. But I couldn't figure out the reason, what I am missing, and how to resolve it. May anyone explaining to me why I'm getting this behavior and how I could solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
<test-animation [show]="showAnimation"></test-animation>
```

Comment: `<test-animation show="{{showAnimation}}"></test-animation>` passes the string `"true"` or `"false"` while `[show]="showAnimation"` passes the value `true` or `false` (or whatever value `showAnimation holds). `{{xxx}}` always stringifies the value before assinging it.

Comment: That was exactly that I was missing. Thank you so much for the explanation as well, now is clear what was my mistake.

Comment: @mvermand Thanks , It worked for me . Also Danke fur explanation Gunter Zochbauer :) .